# Paypal - REST API credit card credentials Name vs. Company

Tags: paypal

Need help to accept business credit card credentials.

The REST API for credit cards needs the fields "First Name" and "Last Name" in case of a business credit card the card usually shows "Company Name" in line 1 and the name of the employee allowed to use the card which is the second line.

Should I put the company name in "First Name" and the employee name in "Last Name"?

Many thanks for fast response as I have to implement it for my client.

Answer (score 1):

I would just go with the first and last name of the employee and that should work out fine for you.

Comment: Would you at least keep the company data within the application environment linked to the credit card id? And how do you deal with middle initials?

Comment: In my experience the name that you send to the gateway to process the payment really has no effect.  For local storage purposes, though, yes, I like to keep as much detail as possible.